# Даты в dbf FoxPro через TADOQuery

Tags: delphi, база-данных, запрос, дата

Подключаюсь к FoxPro .DBF из Delphi через TADOQuery (драйвер VFPOLEDB.1). Возникла проблема с выборкой записей, даты которых находятся в выбранном диапазоне. Перепробовал разные варианты, но они либо возвращают в набор всю таблицу, либо выпадают с разными ошибками.

```
where updatedate < {^2009-11-11}
```

или

```
where updatedate < Date(2009,11,11)
```

=> Возвращают "Operator type mismatch"

```
where updatedate < '11.11.2009'
```

или

```
where updatedate < [11.11.2009]
```

=> Возвращают всю таблицу, без отбора по дате

При попытке подсунуть дату как параметр, получаем тот же "Operator type mismatch"

```
where TTOD(updatedate) <= CTOD("11.11.2009")
```

=> Получаем "Function argument value, type, or count is invalid"

Как сделать выборку по датам в определенном диапазоне?

Comment: Оказалось, что проблема в хранении дат. Они записываются "строкой" в виде dd.mm.yyyy. В настройках FoxPro по умолчанию даты имеют вид mm.dd.yyyy(MDY). Нашел в реестре эти настройки. После изменения на DMY ничего не происходит. В TADOQuery пробовал перед запросом принудительно указать SET DATE DMY или GERMAN, возвращает "Произошла одна или несколько ошибок при выполнении запроса". Как можно, не изменяя значений в таблице, работать со строковым полем такого формата, как с датой?

Answer (score 1):

А если попробовать BETWEEN?

```
<поле> [NOT] BETWEEN <начало> AND <конец>
```

Подробнее можно почитать [тут](http://www.sql.ru/forum/931819-1/vyvod-daty-s-pomoshhu-operatora-between)

Comment: Спасибо. Проблема не в самом "промежутке".

Answer (score 0):

Все приведённые варианты и сообщения об ошибках говорят, что поле `updatedate` имеет строковый тип, и сравнивать его с датой некорректно.
Попробуйте так:

```
where CTOD(updatedate) < {^2009-11-11}
```

Но учтите, что результат функции `ctod()` зависит от настройки set date.